# Make TH Text inside a jquery ui resizable DIV go under the next TH if it does not fit the column width

Tags: html, jquery-ui-resizable

I have this headers on a table with a div inside:

```
<TH><DIV class="resize">Name of Column</DIV></TH>
<TH><DIV class="resize">Name of Column2</DIV></TH>

$(".resize").resizable();
```

So when the user resizes the column "Name of Column" it will be cut in spaces, and if the text inside the div is greater than the text in all TDs of the TBODY then the letters are kept outside the dividing line.

What I want is that if this happens the header text from column1 will be under column2. For example:

If this is the | dividing line at the beginning I'll have this:

Name of Column | Name of column2

When I resize it goes like this:

Nam|e
of    |            Name of Column2
Col  |umn
       |
1     |
2     |
3     |

And I want it to be like this:

Nam|
of    |      Name of Column2
Col  |
       |
1     |
2     |
3     |

So as you can see the text will remain under the second TH.

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PgScg/)

```
.hideOverflow{overflow:hidden}
```

You just need to hide the overflow content.

```
<TH><DIV class="resize hideOverflow">Name of Column</DIV></TH>
<TH><DIV class="resize hideOverflow">Name of Column2</DIV></TH>
```

Comment: Great that worked like a charm... But now I have another issue hehe... When the the td text is greater than the TH header text the dividing line stops when the td cannot be reduced but the div from the header continues reducing itself. How do I make it stop at the same time that the TH does?

Comment: I think I can even add overflow to every td, how can I accomplish that?

Comment: yes you can add the same class to any element to make that resizable, and hide overflow.

Comment: add the class  to the table. to make the table resizable.

Comment: or define the css as #mytableId tr td{overflow:hidden}  to apply all the td of that table

Comment: I did what you told me to, but the TD keeps shrinking to its biggest word and the div in TH continue to go smaller than TH width

Comment: Never mind... I fix it by putting DIVs surrounding every TD text with a class that do the same overflow:hidden and call the alsoResize option from jqueryUI Resizable.